# HERE Maps: Customize the color of a MapLocalModel

Tags: android, here-api

I used the sample code here: https://tcs.ext.here.com/sdk_examples/CustomPositionMarker.zip to create a custom marker.
Now I'm wondering is it possible to change the color of a MapLocalModel from black. I actual have an arrow image I'd like to use instead. I tried using setTexture but it didn't see to have any effect. Do you have some sample code that demonstrates how to set a texture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapLocalModel#setTexture will only provide an image. You will need to add texture mapping coordinates to tell how to map the image to the 3d model. Please see the following [link](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mesh.html#topic-apiref__settexturecoordinates-floatbuffer).

Think of this API as just like an OpenGL rendering. You supply a set of triangle, a set of indicies to render the triangles into a shape. You apply an image for texturing, and a set of [u,v] coordinates to map each vertex to the texture to rasterize the output.

If you want an object with a solid color, you can use a Phong material to shade the mesh. Please see this [link](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-mapping-mapmodelobject-phongmaterial.html) for solid coloring.